# Issue in youtube-api (php) :: $youtube->search->listSearch not working with topicId

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am using **topicID to filter** my queries to the Youtube Data API, and recive back only video about recipes.

My code is the following:
**$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array('q' => $queryString, 'maxResults' => 50, 'type' => 'video', 'topicId' => '/m/0p57p', ));**

It was working until Friday 17th of January, but then it stops working; **If I use the parameter 'topicId' => '/m/0p57p' the query gives back to me NO results.**

I have also tried with different topicIDs but no one is working.

Anyone have any idea on why what to do?

Thank you in advance, MT

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already opened the bug in issue tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5824

I filed internally, and linked it. You can track the progress of fix.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim. Do you have any news on that? It seems nothing changes since Jan-19, are already 17 days :(